# How to make RESTful root keys in versioned Active model serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, active-model-serializers, serialization

I have ruby on rails app with user_controller generated via scaffold.

```
 # app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb
 class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::ApiController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  serialization_scope :view_context

   def show
     render json: @user
   end
 end
```

The model

```
  # app/models/api/v1/user.rb
  class Api::V1::User < Api::V1::ApiRecord
    has_one_time_password

    validates_presence_of :phone
  end
```

And serializer:

```
 # app/serializers/api/v1/user_serializer.rb
  class Api::V1::UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :phone, :first_name, :email, :dob, :last_name, :gender, :otp_code

    def otp_code
        object.otp_code
    end
  end
```

Everything is fine but i got stuck in configuration. `/api/v1/users/2` gives me below response.

```
   {
    "api/v1/user": {
        "id": 2,
        "phone": "999999999",
        "first_name": "Rajan",
        "email": "sample@h.com",
        "dob": "2000-01-01",
        "last_name": "Verma",
        "gender": "male",
        "otp_code": "503036"
      }
   }
```

Did you saw the root key? why it is coming with full namespace? it should be `{ "user": { ...data } }` only.

I don't want to apply and patch or hacks for this trivial one. I think i am missing any configuration which i am not able to find in documentation.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using `ActiveModel::Serializer` ?

Comment: yes. Is that wrong?

Comment: No that's alright there are just different serialization libs and depending which you use the answer is different.

Comment: Not to be “that guy” but have you tried the https://github.com/fast-jsonapi/fast_jsonapi gem instead of ASM? If you’re at the early stage it might be worth switching as it’s much much faster.

Comment: @TomHarvey  ASM has  issues i know... but Json_api is horrible..  i have spends months on that fixing manually.. how such gem can be so pupular. json_api has unneccessary complicated the simple strructure of responses.  For showing a list you need to make N independent requests for corresponding ID'S which can be easily nested in a single object.

Comment: Also If you try to embed relations they always go in separate object. Why? you have all data in single object still you need to write extra code to map them. and if you want to develop for mobile... having 2 simple references make your object nested 7 level deep.. who wants that in real world..??   have a look at this comment and thread https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/307#issuecomment-476176835

Comment: I see; you don’t want the JsonApi spec, fair enough. If you are following that spec the gem is good, otherwise not so

Comment: Json_api spec is fair for frontend frameworks. but for mobile apps nesting that much deep kills the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems `ActiveModel::Serializer` uses the full model name including modules as the root key, see

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L384-L391

So either you set the `root` key in your controller.

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: @users, root: "users"
  end
end
```

Or if you never want to include the full name in your serializer you could create a base serializer

```rb
# app/serializers/api/base_serializer.rb
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def json_key
    object.class.model_name.to_s.demodulize.underscore
  end
end

# app/serializers/api/v1/user_serializer.rb
class Api::V1::UserSerializer < BaseSerializer
  attributes :id, :phone, :first_name, :email, :dob, :last_name, :gender, :otp_code

  def otp_code
    object.otp_code
  end
end
```

Comment: I got the idea..  But It gives `undefined method root' for Api::V1::UserSerializer:Class` .

Comment: Ah you're right, root needs to be set in the controller. I think I would go with the second option though and implement a base serializer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that your model is `Api::V1::User` which most probably was autogenerated by the scaffold.

Are you sure you'll be needing versioning in your model?

Maybe having a model `User` and apply the namespacing versioning to solely to your controllers and routes will be enough for your application.

If you do want to have the `Vx` namespace to your models as well, then you can override the `json_key` as [Christian Bruckmayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443871/687142) suggests, either to all serializers or explicitly to `Api::V1::UserSerializer`

Comment: Yes, I dont think we need to version the models. I have remove that..

Answer (score 0):

What is https://github.com/bsm/serialization_scopes doing in there? The line `serialization_scope :view_context` could be removed no?

Comment: That's for accessing current_user and other helper methods in serializer... Irrelevant to this question. I Forgot to remove